# How to return a Json response from a service layer (Dot net core 3.1)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a question. I have a dot net core 3.1 app. I have a appointment controller which calls
a appointment service. The appointment calls a validation service to validate some values in de database. I want to stop the execution if the value doesn't exists in the database.
I want to return a list of response to the client from the validation service.

How can i a return a response from the validation service?

code example:

```
public async Task<bool> Validate() { 
bool ValidateOK = await 
_validateService.ValidateObjects(ObjectsToValidate); 
if (ValidateOK == false) //Throw list of Errors en messages return true; 
}
```

```
Responses wil be like this
{
   Errorcode: 201
   ErrorMessage: Value1 doesn't exists in the database
}
{
   Errorcode: 201
   ErrorMessage: Value2 doesn't exists in the database
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to return the json to the front-end or is it necessary in your code? 
Could you also show some code that highlights what you have tried or what the state of these functions is.

Comment: I'm trying to return to the front end. The code is pretty standaard.  The validatio  service checks some value in the database en if they don't exists it must return a response and stop execution. Correction: I want to throw a list of errors and messages to the front end if the values doesn't exists.

Comment: public async Task<bool> Validate()
        {
            bool ValidateOK = await _validateService.ValidateObjects(ObjectsToValidate);
            if (ValidateOK == false)
                //Throw list of Errors en messages
                

            return true;
        }

Comment: Could you edit your question instead of posting in the comments you can use markdown to make it a code block. I will answer your question

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question. I hope i have done it right.

Comment: you can select the code part and press ctrl + k to mark it as code block

Comment: I hope it's ok now

Comment: Looks good to me, currently working on a detailed answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244789/discussion-between-rbdeenk-and-user3552264).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a Json response you should change the return `Type` of the function/ method used as the endpoint. This is the first function that gets called by the front-end.

I'd recommend creating a custom class in this case. This will make it easy to implement more specific handling of the response. And will make it more accessible for different parts of your application.

The class would look like this (you can manipulate it to fit your needs):

```
public class Response
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Your `Validate` function should look like this:

```
public async Task<Response> Validate(type objectToValidate)
{
    // validation process
    if (!validated) return response;
}
```

Don't forget to set the `Type` in the parameters to whatever you need to validate.
Your `Validate` function is not responsible for talking to the front-end. So you wouldn't want it to return Json.

Your `Endpoint` will look like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> MyEndpoint()
{
    // your code
    var response = await _validateService.Validate(objectToValidate);
    return Json(response);
}
```

You might need to reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`.

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer. I will try to implement this and let you know if it's working. Again many thanks.

Comment: Have you managed to implement this code? Let me know if you need any further help of any kind.

Comment: hi rbdeenk, again thanks for your answer. This really helped me. Another question i have: can i have the execution abort in de validation service en list the errors in the response and not going back to the calling service/controller? The reason for this question is that the validation service is a generic service which is used bij different controller/services.

Comment: It's important to understand that your validation service is nothing more than a validation. It shouldn't handle the controllers work, it's the controllers responsibility to handle requests from and to the front-end. So you'd have to implement the return on every controller call that uses the validation.

Comment: Any time! (Geen probleem :))